# 2d array error: row index printing

Tags: c++

Actually i was tying to print 2d array by user. Then adding the number row wise.
I don't know how to print row index number. The code is:

```
int arr[3][3];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        cin >> arr[i][j];
}

cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j= 0; j < 3; j++)
        cout<< arr[i][j]<<" ";
    cout << endl;
}


for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)

        sum += arr[x][y];
    cout << "Row: " << arr[x] << "addition is:" << sum << endl;
    sum = 0;
}
```

In 2nd last row arr[x] print the address.
If i use arr[x][y] it tells ( 'y' is undefined). why 'y' is undefined ?
And kindly someone tell me how to add numbers diagonally...?

Answer (score 2):

Well `arr[x]` is an array, which decays to a pointer to its first element. So when you print `arr[x]` you are in fact printing `&arr[x][0]`.

I assume you want to print `x` only:

```
cout << "Row: " << x << ...
```

Answer (score 1):

'y' is undefined because it went out of its scope.

To add numbers diagonally, you can do:

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    sum += arr[i][i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use brackets on loops always. This

```
 for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    sum += arr[x][y];
 cout << "Row: " << arr[x] << "addition is:" << sum << endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
 for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    sum += arr[x][y];
 }
 cout << "Row: " << arr[x] << "addition is:" << sum << endl;
```

and outside of the loop `y` is not declared. You probably wanted

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
   sum += arr[x][y];
   cout << "Row: " << arr[x] << "addition is:" << sum << endl;
}
```

Further, you say you want to print the row index, which is either `x` or `y`, but not `arr[x][y]` which is the element at index `[x][y]`.